# How to add dynamic html table data to firestore in one write?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a table where users enter product details such as item, price and quantity.
I thought of using tuples.
But it is complex.
Is there any way of storing this dynamic data and add to firestore.

```
    var table_data = document.getElementById('table-body-bill');
var table_length= table_data.rows.length;
for(var i=0;i<table_length;i++){
    upload_bill_data=x+'[';
    upload_bill_data = upload_bill_data +  'itemName:' + table_data.rows[i].cells.item(0).innerHTML + ','; 
    upload_bill_data = upload_bill_data +  'price:' + table_data.rows[i].cells.item(1).innerHTML + ',';
    upload_bill_data = upload_bill_data +  'quantity:' + table_data.rows[i].cells.item(2).innerHTML;  
   x++;
    }

upload_bill_data += ']';
console.log(upload_bill_data);

}

db.collection('22')
.add({
 tt:   upload_bill_data
})'`

//Output looks like 
 upload_bill_data = 1{itemName:"",price:"", quantity:""}
//everything gets stored as a single variable

//But I want the data to be like this. 
upload_bill_data = 1 {
itemName:"",
price:"", 
quantity:""
}
//It should store it in different elements
```

Comment: Try `tt: JSON.parse(upload_bill_data)` after removing iteration variable `x` from concatenating. You are sending tt as a string.

Comment: Hi @Devv, can you please describe whether the above comment helped you or if you need further help? In case your issue is solved, can you please post an answer with the steps you took for other users who run into the same issue? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I did't knew how to reply to an answer. Thank you, I implement led it and I got the desired result. Thank you @isuru89

Answer (score 0):

From comment above:

Try `tt: JSON.parse(upload_bill_data)` after removing iteration variable x from concatenating. You are sending tt as a string.